# Issue with Angular2 file manager - cannot find modules

Tags: angular, typescript

I trying to run this file manager in my application: 
[Angular2 file manager](https://github.com/qjon/angular/tree/master/projects/filemanager)

The issue occurs inside app module, where i want to import this modules. At this moment it looks like this:

```
...
import { FileManagerModule } from '@rign/angular2-filemanager';
import { TreeModule } from '@rign/angular2-tree';
import { ConfirmationPopoverModule } from 'angular-confirmation-popover';
...
 imports: [
    FileManagerModule.forRoot(fileManagerConfiguration),
    TreeModule.forRoot(),
    ConfirmationPopoverModule.forRoot(),
...
```

I can't deal with these errors:

> ```
> ERROR in projects/file-manager/src/app/app.module.ts(26,35): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@rign/angular2-filemanager'.
> projects/file-manager/src/app/app.module.ts(27,28): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@ring/angular2-tree'.
> projects/file-manager/src/app/app.module.ts(51,31): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'fileManagerConfiguration'.
> projects/file-manager/src/app/app.module.ts(53,5): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ConfirmationPopoverModule'
> ```

Trying

```
npm i @rign/angular2-filemanager --save
npm i @rign/angular2-tree --save
npm install --save angular-confirmation-popover
```

Sadly nothing helps. Somebody know a solution?

## Clue 1

After:

> npm i @rign/angular2-filemanager --save

I have visible angular2-tree in my app, now i try:

> npm i @rign/angular2-filemanager --save

Now angular2-tree disappears and angular2-filemanager appears in app. If i try again add angular2-tree, filemanager disappear. Whats going out?

## Update 1

Ok, i put it inside package.json and i make it forward to this moment with that error (i just want import @rign/angular2-filemanager to my app):

> ERROR in
>   ../../node_modules/@rign/angular2-filemanager/lib/store/fileManagerApi.service.d.ts:14:5
>   - error TS2416: Property 'add' in type 'FileManagerApiService' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'INodeService'.   Type
>   '(node: IOuterNode, parentNodeId?: string | undefined) =>
>   Observable' is not assignable to type '(node: IOuterNode,
>   parentNodeId: string | null) => Observable'.
>       Types of parameters 'parentNodeId' and 'parentNodeId' are incompatible.
>         Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.
>           Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.
>
> 14     add(node: IOuterNode, parentNodeId?: string):
>   Observable;
>          ~~~ ../../node_modules/@rign/angular2-filemanager/lib/store/fileManagerBackendApi.service.d.ts:21:5
>   - error TS2416: Property 'add' in type 'FileManagerBackendApiService' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'INodeService'.
>   Type '(node: IOuterNode, parentNodeId?: string | undefined) =>
>   Observable' is not assignable to type '(node: IOuterNode,
>   parentNodeId: string | null) => Observable'.
>       Types of parameters 'parentNodeId' and 'parentNodeId' are incompatible.
>         Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.
>           Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.
>
> 21     add(node: IOuterNode, parentNodeId?: string):
>   Observable;
>          ~~~ ../../node_modules/@rign/angular2-tree/lib/service/node.service.d.ts:23:5
>   - error TS2416: Property 'add' in type 'NodeService' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'INodeService'.   Type '(node:
>   IOuterNode, parentNodeId?: string | undefined) =>
>   Observable' is not assignable to type '(node: IOuterNode,
>   parentNodeId: string | null) => Observable'.
>       Types of parameters 'parentNodeId' and 'parentNodeId' are incompatible.
>         Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.
>           Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.
>
> 23     add(node: IOuterNode, parentNodeId?: string):
>   Observable;

The code in app module looks like this:

```
// angular
import { NgModule, NgZone} from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { MAT_RIPPLE_GLOBAL_OPTIONS } from '@angular/material';

// ngrx
import { EffectsModule } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import { StoreDevtoolsModule } from '@ngrx/store-devtools';

// mpcore
import {
  MpCoreModule,
  TokenService,
  LonginusLoggerService,
  LonginusLogger,
  MpTranslateModule,
  TRANSLATION_STORE,
  CoreService,
  IS_PRODUCTION,
  MpTranslateService,
  MpTranslationLoader,
  MpMissingTranslationHandler
} from 'mpcore';
// translate
import { TranslateLoader, TranslateService, MissingTranslationHandler } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslationStore } from './shared/classes/TranslationStore';
// routing
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
// shared
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
// components
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MainComponent } from './main/main.component';

import { FileManagerModule, IFileManagerConfiguration } from '@rign/angular2-filemanager';
import { TreeModule } from '@rign/angular2-tree';
import { ConfirmationPopoverModule } from 'angular-confirmation-popover';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { ContextMenuComponent } from 'ngx-contextmenu';

const fileManagerConfiguration: IFileManagerConfiguration = {
  urls: {
    foldersUrl: '/api/folder',
    filesUrl: '/api/files',
    folderMoveUrl: '/api/folder/move'
  },
  isMultiSelection: true,
  mimeTypes: ['image/jpg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/png'],
  maxFileSize: 50 * 1024,
  allowChooseMultipleFiles: true
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, MainComponent],
  imports: [
    FileManagerModule.forRoot(fileManagerConfiguration),
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ConfirmationPopoverModule.forRoot(),
    TreeModule.forRoot(),
    ContextMenuComponent,
    BrowserModule,
    SharedModule,
    MpCoreModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
    MpTranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useClass: MpTranslationLoader,
        deps: [TRANSLATION_STORE]
      },
      missingTranslationHandler: { provide: MissingTranslationHandler, useClass: MpMissingTranslationHandler, deps: [CoreService] },
      isolate: true,
      useDefaultLang: true
    }) ,
      StoreModule.forRoot(
      {},
      {
        runtimeChecks: {
          strictActionImmutability: true,
          strictActionSerializability: true,
          strictStateImmutability: true,
          strictStateSerializability: true
        }
      }
    ),
    EffectsModule.forRoot([]),
    !environment.production
      ? StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({
          maxAge: 25, // Retains last 25 states
          logOnly: !environment.production,
          serialize: {
            options: {
              undefined: true
            }
          } // Restrict extension to log-only mode
        })
    : []
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: IS_PRODUCTION, useValue: environment.production },
    { provide: TRANSLATION_STORE, useValue: new TranslationStore() },
    MpTranslateService,
    { provide: TranslateService, useExisting: MpTranslateService },
    { provide: MAT_RIPPLE_GLOBAL_OPTIONS, useValue: { disabled: true } }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private tokenService: TokenService, private coreService: CoreService, private longinusLoggerService: LonginusLoggerService, private zone: NgZone) {
    this.coreService.siteId = environment.production ? '' : environment.siteId;
    this.coreService.branch = environment.production ? '%Branch%' : environment.branch;
    Date.prototype.toJSON = function() {
      const isValidDate = new Date(this).toString() !== 'Invalid Date' && !isNaN(new Date(this).getTime());
      if (isValidDate) {
        return '/Date(' + (this as Date).getTime().toString() + ')/';
      } else {
        return '';
      }
    };
    LonginusLogger.CreateInstance(this.tokenService, this.longinusLoggerService, 'file-manager', this.zone);
  }
}
```

Comment: And you've verified that they're in your `node_modules` folder? The code seems correct, and [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z7xrw9) example app has no issue resolving the modules. I would suggest that you delete your `node_modules`, ensure that the packages are registered in `package.json` and then run an `npm install` again.

Comment: Yes but only one can be in time, i need both ...

Comment: Have you tried to add them to the `package.json` and then run `npm install`?

Comment: Yes, i made progress but still can't run app. I add more details in #Update 1.